# rsync always uploads all files from macOS => Linux

Tags: macos, rsync, webdav

I'm testing rsync with WebDAV server in Docker container:

- local directory: /Users/user/files/
- "remote" mounted server: /Volumes/webdav/

Here's the initial state:

```
# remote
➜  cat /Volumes/webdav/remotefile
change
➜  ls -la  /Volumes/webdav/remotefile
-rwx------  1 user  staff  7 Dec  2 01:39 /Volumes/webdav/remotefile

# local
➜  cat /Users/user/files/remotefile
change
➜  ls -la  /Users/user/files/remotefile
-rwx------  1 user  staff  7 Dec  2 01:39 /Users/user/files/remotefile
```

Now let's change local file and upload it to "remote" server:

```
➜  files echo 'add#0' > ./remotefile
➜  files cat remotefile
add#0
➜  files \rsync -varP /Users/user/files/* /Volumes/webdav/ --delete
building file list ...
1 file to consider
remotefile
           6 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=0/1)

sent 132 bytes  received 42 bytes  348.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6  speedup is 0.03
```

File uploads successfully, as it was changed. But if I run rsync again local => remote, it re-uploads it:

```
➜  files \rsync -varP /Users/user/files/* /Volumes/webdav/ --delete
building file list ...
1 file to consider
remotefile
           6 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=0/1)

sent 132 bytes  received 42 bytes  348.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6  speedup is 0.03
```

**Now I test opposite direction:**

```
➜  files \rsync -varP /Volumes/webdav/* /Users/user/files/ --delete
building file list ...
1 file to consider
remotefile
           6 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=0/1)

sent 132 bytes  received 42 bytes  348.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6  speedup is 0.03
```

File downloads succesfully. And one more time...

```
➜  files \rsync -varP /Volumes/webdav/* /Users/user/files/ --delete
building file list ...
1 file to consider

sent 80 bytes  received 20 bytes  200.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6  speedup is 0.06
```

...shows 0 transfers, as file was not changed. Thats the expected behavour.

Why it doesn't work with local => remote upload and always re-uploads file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you confirmed that the clocks are in sync on both `local` and `remote`?

From the [rsync man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

```
 Rsync finds files that need to be transferred using a lqquick checkrq algorithm 
 (by default) that looks for files that have changed in size 
 or in last-modified time.
```

If the clocks *are* out of sync, and you are not able to edit one, try telling rsync to be a little "fuzzier" with how it checks for time.   Again from the man page for [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

```
 --modify-window
    When comparing two timestamps, rsync treats the timestamps 
    as being equal if they differ by no more than the modify-window value. 
    This is normally 0 (for an exact match), but you may find it useful 
    to set this to a larger value in some situations. 
    In particular, when transferring to or from an MS Windows FAT filesystem 
    (which represents times with a 2-second resolution), 
    --modify-window=1 is useful (allowing times to differ by up to 1 second).
```

Try running rsync with the `--size-only` option and seeing if the behavior of `rsync` changes.

Another alternative is to use the `--checksum` option to rsync.  This requires more disk I/O and cycles to generate checksums, so it can be slower.  It would be interesting to know if it shifts the problem.

---

Comment: Brilliant guess! `date && docker exec 1c3f5cb52a55 date => Fri Dec  2 02:18:09 MSK 2016 
Thu Dec  1 23:18:09 UTC 2016`

Comment: `--size-only` works as expected, but if only file symbol in file changed, it obviously considered file was not changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't control remote server time as it's third-party webdav server. size-only is unreliable. Are there any workarounds? For example, how Dropbox solves similar problems? I suppose they should use similar algorithm.

Comment: Moscow Standard Time (MSK) is UTC +3, which makes me think the clocks *are* in sync.  Maybe something else is at play here.

Comment: Ah, I've got you. Rsync respects TZ shifts, so the time is technically the same. Right now I'm playing with `--checksum` option, and it seems to work at first look. But not sure, how it will work with remote 50GB server with millions of files. Thanks for pointing out direction.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are passing --times (-t) to rsync. This causes modification time to be copied over.

Otherwise, if you immediately run rsync again, it will see all files as "changed", and in need of copying (again!). This is because by default, rsync does the following:

1. Looks at size and modification time to determine whether a file has changed.
2. Does NOT copy over modification time.

(I like how by default, rsync shoots itself in the foot.)

--archive (-a) implies --times, so no need to use --times if you are already using --archive.